# mysql performance question

Tags: php, mysql

Is a search through numbers (INT) faster than characters in an mySQL database?
Regards,
Thijs

Comment: as a matter of fact, the characters are numbers too. And, you know, nobody searches "through" these days. But rather do index lookups.

Comment: Probably yes, but that depends. Is there an index on the columns in question? If so, what kind of index? What type is the "character column"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice the difference will be small - it will increase depending on the relative length of the 2 fields. The question pre-supposes that 2 are interchangeable - which is a very bad assumption given that MySQL natively supports an ENUM data-type.

If it's that important to you, why not measure it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be. An `int` is only 4 bytes, while in a text (`varchar`) might be considerably bigger.

Besides, if you have an index on the field you are searching, it will be smaller in size. Hence, you might need fewer disk accesses to do an `index scan`.

Comment: In general i agree, though the char() type can have less that 4 bytes and is fixed length so a 2 byte char field may search faster than INT. In real world situations it probably won't be that noticable.

Comment: @Jaydee: true. Thanks for pointing that out. OP mentioned that he/she is storing numbers on the varchar field anyway, so it's very likely to be the case that varchar field will contain more than 4 bytes.

Comment: @Jaydee - in which case use tinyint unsigned (1 byte 0..255)

Comment: I think the general point we can agree on is that the field size is (usually) more important than the type.

Answer (score 1):

If the INT and VARCHAR consumes the same amount of space the difference should be negligible, even though INT probably will come out on top.

Databases don't use black magic. They need to physically access data like everyone else. Table rows consume disk space. Reading 100 mb is faster than reading 200 mb. Always.

Therefore. this affects everything. Smaller rows means more rows per "block". More rows per block means more rows fetched per disk access. Fewer blocks in total means that a larger percentage of the rows will fit in various buffer caches.